# Low battery life in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, along dual booting  Windows 7.

I love Ubuntu but then suddenly the power went out and the next thing I know my battery ran out of juice in less than 30 minutes.

Usually my battery lasts for 3 hours with Windows 7, but on Ubuntu its considerably less please give me some advice.

Comment: Did you have the laptop plugged into the charger when the power went out?

Comment: yeah sure I had it plugged in

Comment: You probably shorted out the battery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Optimize your screen brightness**, so it consumes less power.

Or you should also **monitor your system activities by ctrl + tab** and see if any process consuming lots of CPU and resources, Consuming more CPU results more heat up and less power.

Or you can install PowerTop to see what's taking the power so you can optimise your system.

To install: `sudo apt-get install powertop`

Comment: sorry to tell you man but I've already tried doing that :(

Comment: install powertop tool or you should see it http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Manage-Your-Laptop-Battery-in-Ubuntu-to-Make-it-Last-Longer&id=4319612

Comment: could you please elaborate>>>???

Comment: Powertop is a command line tool which will show you which process consuming more power.

sudo apt-get install powertop

To run it **sudo powertop**

Comment: Thanx a lot :):):):)

Comment: @Sharmarahul I've edited your question to include the answer which you had not given in the answer but as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

For me `tlp` has worked best. Try installing it as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html). You will have to purge `laptop-mode-tools` package if it is installed on your system else `tlp` will refuse to start.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is also overheating and with the fan constantly on, it could be something to do with your **graphics card** and their drivers.

But for an adequate answer find out what graphics card your have (you can find out by running `lspci` in the terminal).

Comment: Could you elaborate what tweaks you did to fglrx to conserve power? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You may wish to improve/expand on your answer. Or if you cannot you may wish to move this to a comment.

Comment: Actually, to fix my problem I had with my radeon card (in ubutnu 13.04) I added the following code to my rc.local to disable vgaswitcharoo: 

`chown USER /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch 

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch 

modprobe radeon`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the user interface. Unity is heavy enough, so you have lightweight user interface choices such as XFCE (lightweight), LXDE (more lightweight), or Openbox (very lightweight). Try to install one and relogin by choosing user interface you have installed in the display manager.

## XFCE

[image]

## LXDE

[image]

## Openbox

[image: http://restava.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/openbox-tint2-conky8.png]