# Ubuntu 16.04 battery issues

Tags: power-management, battery, inspiron

I have serious battery malfunction with ubuntu 16.04. It's not only that it went to a regular 2-3 hours on windows 10 to less than 30 minutes with ubuntu. It's also that it takes forever to charge, and also sometimes, it does not detect the A/C charger, so it doesn't charge. 
I tried several things, like instaling TLP. Then replacing it with Laptop Mode Tools. 
None of that worked. I have been monitoring my PC with powertop, but cannot really understand what the problem might b. It's really quite an issue,can someone please help me? 
I have an inspiron 5555

Comment: Hi @ArmandoTorres, I don't think that the OS has anything to do with charging; I believe that the BIOS (or the UEFI) determines whether the computer recognizes the charger and its capabilities.  I could be wrong, of course.  Maybe you have been led astray by coincidence?  To be specific, maybe you have an intermittent charger, and it was working when you were running Windows, and not working when you tried Ubuntu.  Does the charger work when the computer is off?  (If you want to reply in a comment, then please put an ampersand followed by my user name in the comment, or I'll never see it.)

Comment: @rclocher3 Thanks for answering ! Well, the charger does work when the computer is off. It does take a long time. And then, when fully charged, the battery doesn't last over 20 mins.

Comment: The battery should last about the same amount of time in Windows or Ubuntu.  If it only lasts 20 minutes, I think the battery needs to be replaced.

Comment: @ rclocher3 My pc is two-weeks new. I have double boot. Whenever I go back to windows, battery life is re-established.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that Armando.  You have tried the ideas from [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/497692/low-battery-life-in-ubuntu-14-04) so I can't think what else to try next.